# localStorage commands stops the program

Tags: javascript

Whenever i use save button and load button ( they work ) but stop the game. After I click load, the game freezes, buttons and animations work, but the game freezes and i cannot get xp or gold.

my code:

```
function save(){
  localStorage["gold"] = gold;
  localStorage["goldmax"] = goldmax;
  localStorage["food"] = food;
  localStorage["foodmax"] = foodmax;
  localStorage["wood"] = wood;
  localStorage["woodmax"] = woodmax;
  localStorage["stone"] = stone;
  localStorage["stonemax"] = stonemax;
  localStorage["iron"] = iron;
  localStorage["ironmax"] = ironmax;
  localStorage["level"] = level;
  localStorage["xp"] = xp;
  localStorage["xpN"] = xpN;
  localStorage["xpgained"] = xpgained;
  localStorage["questpoint"] = questpoint;
  localStorage["questpointspeed"] = questpointspeed;
  localStorage["buildQueue"] = buildQueue;
  localStorage["buildSpeed"] = buildSpeed;
  localStorage["heroxp"] = heroxp;
  localStorage["herolevel"] = herolevel;
  localStorage["skillpoint"] = skillpoint;
  spop("Game has been successfully saved!")
}
function load(){
  if (localStorage.getItem("gold") === null){
    spop('<strong>Save file has been corrupted!</strong>', 'error');
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("gold") !== null){
    gold =            localStorage["gold"];
    goldmax =         localStorage["goldmax"];
    food =            localStorage["food"];
    foodmax =         localStorage["foodmax"];
    wood =            localStorage["wood"];
    woodmax =         localStorage["woodmax"];
    stone =           localStorage["stone"];
    stonemax =        localStorage["stonemax"];
    iron =            localStorage["iron"];
    ironmax =         localStorage["ironmax"];
    level =           localStorage["level"];
    xp =              localStorage["xp"];
    xpN =             localStorage["xpN"];
    xpgained =        localStorage["xpgained"];
    questpoint =      localStorage["questpoint"];
    questpointspeed = localStorage["questpointspeed"];
    buildQueue =      localStorage["buildQueue"];
    buildSpeed =      localStorage["buildSpeed"];
    heroxp =          localStorage["heroxp"];
    herolevel =       localStorage["herolevel"];
    skillpoint =      localStorage["skillpoint"];
    spop("Game has been successfully loaded!")
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in development console?

Comment: Comes up with, gold.toFixed(2) is not a function. Is it because localStorage stores it as string ? or something ?

Comment: Yes, localStorage stores all data in strings. Can you show us part of code that causes error?

Comment: When your game loads which function being called for the first time ? either the `load()` function or any other function you have for that ?

Comment: The load function only runs if gold has saved data. Meaning you have to save first to load it then. This is my code for gold bit:

Comment: document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = "Gold: "+gold.toFixed(2)+" / "+goldmax.toFixed(0);

Answer (score 0):

localStorage saves all data in Strings. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dcs90c2/)

So you have to convert it to Number:

```
parseInt(localStorage["gold"]);
```

Comment: your fiddle is not working :) Please wrap javascript in head in your fiddle :)
then your fiddle will work.

Comment: Please, try it now.

Comment: Still not working ! use this fiddle instead [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dcs90c2/7/) :)

Comment: Thank you guys for help, everything worked very well, and i am happy that i finally made a working save system. THANKS AGAIN! :D

Comment: I dont know why but it doesnt seem to work on decimal places, i wanted to save variable that had, 0.01 and it didnt save. I did parseFloat and it kept saving number 0;